# 404 Not found error while calling clickbank webservices

Tags: php, rest, clickbank

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$ch = curl_init();
//$qry_str='?&type=RFND&comment="API refund check"&reason=ticket.type.cancel.7&refundType=FULL';
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/N5GNE72J/'.$qry_str);
//https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/RRBKQV4E/?type=rfnd&comment=&reason=ticket.type.refund.7&refundType=FULL
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/RRBKQV4E");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/RRBKQV4E/?type=RFND&comment=&reason=ticket.type.cancel.7&refundType=FULL");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '180');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml","Authorization:DEV-B4VTK7HDKAPDR9842SODK8GI49KAHTHL:API-59RD4F7BORDB7SELOII28DV0EMLIB3IT"));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$errorCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$curlError = curl_error($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

When above code is run I am getting below error :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
Date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 08:14:19 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.40 mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/0.9.8y 
Content-Length: 363 
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Type: text/html
```

Please someone help, I am struggling with this for last 1 week but no success.

Comment: It's not about your code, it's about your link. It indeed returns a 404 error

Comment: Having a quick look at the API, it seems to be waiting for an integer instead of a string for the ticket id. For `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/RRBKQV4E` you get 404, but for `https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/456` you get 403, which means it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle found the solution. Use below code it worked for me.

```
 <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    "https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/tickets/627JE7CZ/?type=rfnd&comment=&reason=ticket.type.refund.7&refundType=FULL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
/**
 * ClickBank doesn't allow POST parameters to be sent in; however, for the CURL POST to work correctly, the
 * CURL_POSTFIELDS option must be set, so we'll just set it to empty and put all our request parameters on the URL
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Authorization:DEV-enter your dev key here:API-enter your clerk key here"
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```